# Apache Server adding blank lines, possible?

Tags: php, apache, svn, web-hosting, blank-line

After some time I downloaded a copy of a website via FTP.
I made a comparison with SVN and I find out that each file
was modified in this way:

**BEFORE**

```
<div class="class">
    <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```

**AFTER**

```
<div class="class">

    <p>TEXT</p>

</div>
```

Is there some option that could cause this behaviour??

Thank you

Comment: Apache can't edit your files.. I suspect it could have been a program you've used for SVN or perhaps a code editor (they tend to do this if auto-formatting is on).

Comment: Mmm can't be because I use the same IDE for several projects and only this one has the issue. With SVN I use tortoiseSVN and I use it for several projects and none of them has this issue. Could be Cpanel?

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks

Comment: @CBroe Yes I think you may be right. When uploading files through cPanel it may do the conversion (ASCII). That's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out where the problem is.

I didn't upload the files via FTP.
I used cPanel.

```
cPanel 66.0 (build 17)
```

**EDIT**

> To by pass this problem

Simply ZIP all files from cPanel and download the ZIP.
The problem will be solved.

Hope this is useful

**RE-EDIT**

> To solve the problem

In FileZilla => Transfer > Transfer Type

I had "ASCII" selected: by setting "Binary" the problem is solved.